# How to extract an array where the key of that array will be as variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, extract

I have an array/object like data and I want to access every key of the array/object as a variable like below:

```
var data = {};
data['one'] = 1;
data['tow'] = 2;
```

I want to access like below:
    console.log(one);

and expect as output: 1
**I'm looking for an alternative way of extract(array) function from PHP**

Comment: You can't do that in JavaScript. JavaScript doesn't have associative Arrays and Objects don't have a `extract` method.

Comment: `console.log(data.one);` ??

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, you use `{}` for creating Associative Arrays. Like the following:

```
var data = {}
data['one'] = 1;
data['two'] = 2;

console.log(data['one'])
```

or you can use the dot notation:

```
data.one = 1;
data.two = 2;

console.log(data.one)
```

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't cover the second part.

Comment: this is not my question. I want to access key as a variable without any separator

Comment: Yeah, that is not possible in javascript.

Comment: @FaridAlexander If you've already read my answer, you'll find that your sentence is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You either need objects or maps:

```js
const data = {}
data['one'] = 1
data['two'] = 2

console.log(data['one'])

const data2 = new Map()
data2.set('one', 1)
data2.set('two', 2)

console.log(data2.get('one'))
```

Also, the approximation to `extract` would be *destructuring*:

```js
const data = {}
data['one'] = 1
data['two'] = 2

const { one, two } = data

console.log('Destructured from an object: ', one, two)

const data2 = new Map()
data2.set('one', 1)
data2.set('two', 2)

const [[, one2], [, two2]] = data2
const [one3, two3] = data2.values()

console.log('Destructured from map entries: ', one2, two2)
console.log('Destructured from map values: ', one3, two3)
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to add a dynamic value instead of one and two at line 
  const { one, two } = data
in my case, I have a dynamic object. I want to use every key of that as a variable.
is it possible in js?

Comment: @Mahfuz Impossible. Sorry. Unless you implement some kind of language extension using BabelJS, which would involve transpiling your code.

Comment: @Mahfuz If you want to use *any*, just access those values using *dot syntax* (i.e. `data.one`. There's no other way to handle this scenario in JS.